# Getting a reference to third party components in React

Tags: reactjs, react-component, react-ref

If you’re using a 3rd party component and you want to call a method of that component, how do you get a reference to it so that you can call it?
React used to have a prop called  where in the parent component you can call this.refs.myrefname.somemethod(), but looks like react removed the ref prop.

How can the same thing be achieved now?

Comment: features like ref are the only ones, which can actually allow us to do extra ordinary things with DOM, which React can't. So I don't think, they are ever gonna get deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

well.. last i checked, it still works..

Edit: I have already shown the implementation here. anyways posted the code as well. So refs are still in work.

https://codesandbox.io/s/3rd-party-component-i9cbx

```
export default function App() {
  const textFieldRef = createRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    textFieldRef.current.value = "Value";
    textFieldRef.current.focus();
  }, [textFieldRef]);
  return <TextField inputRef={textFieldRef} />;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still curious how this can be achieved without the added support of a library, which in this case looks like is material ui

Comment: @marie146.. so what do you actually mean by a 3rd party component? I have used a material ui component here in my case.